# Disable click event on clipped area from cornered button

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have created a button and added pressed event on it. The button height and width are 300x300 and the corner radius is 150. So it looks like circle.

```
<Button
    WidthRequest="300"
    HeightRequest="300"
    BackgroundColor="Red"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    Margin="20,0,20,0"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    CornerRadius="150">
    <Button.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Pressed"
                                                  Command="{Binding ButtonPressedCommand}" />  
     </Button.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

[image]

The issue is when I click blue area it cahtches pressed event. I want blue area to not catch the event. Now it detects the button as square, not as circle.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, you shouldn't do that. The touch input is imprecise and unless your button is particularly huge those blue areas on your pic are within the bounds of the imprecise measurement and as such should be treated in that way.

If you really need this, you may try with `MR.Gestures.AbsoluteLayout`. Here is an example where it provides the exact point that the user has tapped: https://devtut.github.io/xamarin/gestures.html#place-a-pin-where-the-user-touched-the-screen-with-mr-gestures

Comment: I agree with you but there are two things. I need to create something like darts, so it is important to have that. Also pressed and released event is needed due to requirements I am not sure AbsoluteLayout has that gestures

Comment: @Stefanija This a gestures plugin that has its own AbsoluteLayout Control. It js just called like that, it could be called anything.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can create a custom class which inherites UIButton and override the method [`PointInside`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiview.pointinside?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12).

```
class CustomiOSButton : UIButton
{
    public override bool PointInside(CoreGraphics.CGPoint point, UIKit.UIEvent uievent)
    {
        bool flag = base.PointInside(point, uievent); 
        if (flag)
        {
            UIBezierPath path = UIBezierPath.FromOval(this.Bounds);
            if (path.ContainsPoint(point))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```